# Is there a command to open a new Ikognito Tab with IE by using VBScript?

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, tabs, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-9

Hello Guys I'm here again.

I want to open an "Ikognito-Tab" in IE with VBScript. But i have no idea how I can do it (or if it is even possible). So I ask you all for help. Is there a command to open a new Ikognito Tab with IE by using VBScript?

Thanks

Jonas

Comment: Yep you’re here again and still don’t understand what is involved in providing a well constructed question. You need to give a lot more information than you have before people will be able to help you. Usually a small code sample that details the problem will help in this regard.

Comment: I know that, but i dnon't know what code i should put here because I don't know how to solve this question. But i will do better in future. ;)

Comment: If you don’t know the basics of how to run commands in VBScript using the WSH than you are asking /searching (wishful thinking) the wrong questions, learn to walk before you try to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you are trying to develop a VB script to launch the IE browser in private mode and want to perform some automation tasks.

I suggest you copy and paste the code below in a notepad and save the file with the **.vbs** extension.

```
dim IE

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run ("iexplore -private")

WScript.Sleep 1000

For Each wnd In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
  If InStr(1, wnd.FullName, "iexplore.exe", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    Set IE = wnd

    Exit For
  End If
Next

IE.Navigate("http://localhost/form.html")

 Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
    'Do nothing, wait for the browser to load.
  Loop

  Do While IE.Document.ReadyState <> "complete"
    'Do nothing, wait for the VBScript to load the document of the website.
  Loop
WScript.Sleep 1000
IE.Document.getElementsByName("fname").Item(0).Value = "abc"
WScript.Sleep 1000
IE.Document.getElementsByName("lname").Item(0).Value = "xyz"
```

When you run the above code then it will launch the IE browser in private window then it will navigate to the website and code will fill the data in the textbox.

Output:

[image]

Notes:

1. Make sure to close all the IE instances before running this code.
2. I did not get a direct way to create an IE application object with a private mode. So here I am first opening the IE in private mode using shell and then fetching that object to automate it.

Further, you can try to modify the code as per your own requirements.

Comment: Sorry but that didn't worked. Anyways I need to run commands in the website like this: `Email = webbrowser.document.getElementByID("fe_text").Value` But thanks ;) @Deepak-MSFT

Comment: I suggest you try to provide detailed information. How did you try to run it? Did you get any error? Please explain what does it mean that you want to run the command on the website.

Comment: I ran the program and nothing happened that I could see. I didn't get any error messages either.

By "I want to execute a command on the website, ..." I mean that I want to change the values of the source code. So I want e.g. Fill out forms or log in.

Comment: Please check the updated answer and let me know if have any questions about it.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Perhaps it would have been best waiting for the OP to provide "detailed information" before attempting to answer.

Comment: It anwers my question but the entry on my website does not work properly. But thank you ;)

Comment: @JonasX It may answer your question but what effort did you put into the question? Unfortunately, you won’t learn much if you just keep begging for code instead of taking the time to work through the problem and understand it. Answers like this are just enablers, really a 4K community member should know better.